# How Can i create Tab Contorl in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2012

I tried to create that look like the feature tab control in WPF in visual studio 2012. But I unable to create it. Can any one tell me how can I do it?

Comment: What kind of "tabs" do you mean?  Are you looking for a style for the TabItems for WPF that makes them look like thoses in the VS 2012 IDE, or are you just having problems creating a TabControl?

Comment: Yes I actually want to create a tab control which look like similar to the tab control in visual studio 2010. Since there is no predefined tab control in visual studio express 2012

Answer (score 0):

There is a TabControl in WPF.  True, it's not looking like thoses in VS 2010, but they are there.  The rest is just a question of styling them.  (Unless I am missing something).
Just press the "P" key to change themes.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    KeyUp="Window_KeyUp"
    >
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Test 1" >
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="Test 1" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test 2" >
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="Test 2" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test 3" >
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="Test 3" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test 4" >
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="Test 4" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This generates a simple tab control.
As for styles, there are many styles that you can apply.  Here is a helper class that I created for that:

```
static class ThemeManager
{
    private static ResourceDictionary[] _themes;
    public static ResourceDictionary AeroTheme;
    //public static ResourceDictionary ClassicTheme;
    public static ResourceDictionary LunaTheme;
    public static ResourceDictionary RoyaleTheme;

    private static int _currentIndex = 0;

    public static ResourceDictionary GetNextTheme()
    {
        ResourceDictionary vDict = _themes[_currentIndex];

        if (_currentIndex == _themes.GetUpperBound(0))
            _currentIndex = 0;
        else
            _currentIndex++;

        return vDict;
    }

    static ThemeManager()
    {
        List<ResourceDictionary> vList = new List<ResourceDictionary>();
        Uri themeUri;
        //************
        themeUri = new Uri("PresentationFramework.Aero;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        AeroTheme = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(themeUri);
        vList.Add(AeroTheme);
        //************
        themeUri = new Uri("PresentationFramework.Luna;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Luna.normalcolor.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        LunaTheme = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(themeUri);
        vList.Add(LunaTheme);
        //************
        themeUri = new Uri("PresentationFramework.Luna;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Luna.homestead.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        LunaTheme = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(themeUri);
        vList.Add(LunaTheme);
        //************
        themeUri = new Uri("PresentationFramework.Luna;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Luna.metallic.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        LunaTheme = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(themeUri);
        vList.Add(LunaTheme);
        //************
        themeUri = new Uri("PresentationFramework.Royale;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/Royale.normalcolor.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        RoyaleTheme = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(themeUri);
        vList.Add(RoyaleTheme);
        //************
        /*ClassicTheme = null;
        vList.Add(ClassicTheme);*/
        //************

        _themes = vList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And this is the Window class (to allow to switch themes):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ResourceDictionary _dict;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _dict = ThemeManager.GetNextTheme();
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_dict);
    }

    private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.P) {
            if (_dict != null)
                Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(_dict);

            _dict = ThemeManager.GetNextTheme();
            Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_dict);
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this somehow helps.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Note that I am just presenting the concept of predefined themes, as I assumed that your WPF experience is limitted, and you may not want to jump into creating advanced Styles.  But for the record, if you want anything particular (a button on the tab itself, an image, or anything like that), you will have to style it yourself.  You can find many examples of this on the web.  See this article for a good example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518107/wpf-tabcontrol-styling